# Having generic AsyncTask handle any Exception

Tags: java, android, oop

I have created an generic AsyncTask class, so that I can catch all Exceptions thrown when `task` method is executed:

```
public abstract class Poc<ParamType, ReturnType> 
    extends AsyncTask<ParamType, String, ReturnType> {

    abstract ReturnType task(ParamType... param);

    @Override
    protected ReturnType doInBackground(ParamType... param) {
        try {
            return task(param);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Make some Toast display the exception.
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I try to implement the above class by doing some thing like:

```
public class Use {

    public static void runIt() {
        new Poc<String, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            Boolean task(String... param) {
                return SomeObject.someMethodThatCanThrowAnException(param);
            }
        }.execute("Some String");
    }

}
```

However, it keeps complaining about wanting me to add try/catch statements. Even when I know that `task` will only be called from `doInBackground` which wraps it.

Can I somehow suppress this? Or what is the proper approach without having to add try/catch to every single class that subclasses Poc?

Comment: Did you read the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler is trying to tell you, you need to declare your function as being able to throw things using `throws Exception`.

In this case, you would want the abstract method to be able to throw.

Comment: I've tried a number of things, including adding 'throws Exception' to the abstract definition in Poc. Same error though :-(

Comment: **What does the error say**? Any method that can throw a checked exception must declare it with the `throws` keyword.  That also includes overrides.

Comment: I suck. I was adding it to the method definition instead of the declaration. Waiting for the timer to tick down so I can accept your answer.